# Creating colors with loop

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I would like to create a maximum of twelve different colors by looping with incrementing color values. The problem is I am getting shades of the same color or too bright or too dark.  I am using `interior.color = xxxxxxx`.

Any idea how to achieve some nice colors?

Comment: Have you tried `rgb`?

Comment: Best way to do this is to browse some web sites which deal with this type of thing and create an array to hold the RGB values for palette of your choice - this is easier than trying to programmatically create a set if distintive colors. E.g. see http://colorbrewer2.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll make a nice rainbow :)

```
Sub colors()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    r = 1
    c = 1
    rv = 50
    Do Until rv >= 255
        gv = 50
        r = 1
        Do Until gv >= 255
            bv = 50
            c = 1
            Do Until bv >= 255
                Cells(r, cc + c).Interior.Color = RGB(rv, gv, bv)
                'Print Nnumbers for color
                'Cells(r, cc + c).Value = rv & ", " & gv & ", " & bv
                bv = bv + 20
                c = c + 1
            Loop
            gv = gv + 20
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        rv = rv + 20
        cc = cc + 1
    Loop

    Do Until rv <= 0
        gv = 50
        r = 1
        Do Until gv >= 255
            bv = 50
            c = 1
            Do Until bv >= 255
                Cells(r, cc + c).Interior.Color = RGB(rv, gv, bv)
                'Print Nnumbers for color
                'Cells(r, cc + c).Value = rv & ", " & gv & ", " & bv
                bv = bv + 20
                c = c + 1
            Loop
            gv = gv + 20
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        rv = rv - 20
        cc = cc + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Disclaimer: this doesn't produce a full color wheel, just gets a good portion of the spectrum.  For instance, it's missing the color pink.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Interior.colorindex = i`, `i` being an integer from 0 to 56 as per http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm. Regards,